# Use difference in time with an IF statment in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two times in Python and if last_update is more than 1 hour ahead of time_now run a function

thus far I have

```
last_update = '01:00:00'
time_now = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())

time_now= str(time_now)


FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdiff = datetime.strptime(time_now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(time_update, FMT)
```

which correctly outputs the difference in time. However I can't see how to then use it in a logic statment such as

```
if tdiff > 01:00:00 
   ..do stuff..
```

any ideas..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When parsing just a time (no date), you need to re-combine the resulting object with today's date:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

dt_update = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.strptime(last_update, '%H:%M:%S').time())
```

If you do not do that, you end up with the date `1900-01-01` on the object, but recombining it makes it easier to compare the time to the current time. Just use `datetime.now()` to compare that with:

```
tdiff = datetime.now() - dt_update
```

now you have a `timedelta()` object. Compare it with another `timedelta`:

```
if tdiff > timedelta(hours=1):
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compare them numerically instead of going through `strftime` and then back again. Datetime objects can already compare to each other natively, so just use those:

```
import datetime
    import time

next_update = None
one_hour = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

def f():
    # Do whatever
    next_update = datetime.datetime.now() + one_hour

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now() > next_update:
        f()
    time.sleep(3600) # Now sleep for an hour (or whatever).
```

If you're getting the last_updated parameter from a text file or something, use `strptime` to turn it into a `datetime` like you're already doing, then do the comparison.